# Expression should evaluate to 1 but I get 1 only for certain cases

Tags: complex-numbers

The expression  is $(a - j \mu_1 b) \div (z - \sqrt{z^2 - a^2 - \mu_1^2 b^2})$

$z = a$, the above expression reduces to $(a - j \mu_1 b) \div (a - \sqrt{- \mu_1^2 b^2})$

One way to refactor the above expression is using $j^2 = -1$, the above expression becomes $(a - j \mu_1 b)\div(a - j \mu_1 b)$, which should be 1 for any value of $\mu_1$...

But when I evaluate numerically using Python (`cmath.sqrt()`), I get 1 for $\mu_1 = 1, 2, 3....$ but not for $\mu_1 = 2+2j$ or any other complex number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you have to clarify what you mean by *sqrt*, what Python thinks *sqrt* means, and whether you agree with Python or not. Every (nonzero) complex number has two square roots, and, unlike in the real case, you can't just say "take the positive one". Once you've done that, you'll find that some properties of *sqrt* that hold over real numbers don't hold over the complex numbers, so some manipulations you're doing aren't actually valid.

Comment: Your response led me to using appropriate branch cuts. Thanks